# A bug in YouTube's API example on GAE? Or am I missing something?

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube-api

I'm working with this [list videos example for GAE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python_appengine#retrieve_a_channel_s_uploads) and if you try to run it on that page you can see that there's no `next_page_token`
I've even tried to `self.response.out.write(next_page_token)` and got `None`.

For example purposes I've submitted `Channel name` to be `Google` (which surely has more than 50 videos). I only get 50, no token that I can see, no pagination indication or anything like that.

What am I missing here?

Please advise,
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is the first request pre-filled for you. Click execute at the bottom:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&forUsername=Google&_h=1&

Following that result and hitting the next api in the code,

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA&_h=3&

Clicking execute on that shows that nextPageToken set. Either the code example from Google has a bug in it, or it is a copy paste error somewhere.

EDIT:
There is a bug in the code sample provided.

playlistitems_response looks similar to this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"eYE31WLho912TfxEBDDRSwEQ5Ms/vUtg-sAFafmsExy-5XOvaMIfVN0\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CDQQAA",
 "prevPageToken": "CDIQAQ",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1634,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [{...}]
}
```

The `nextPageToken` is being extracted like `playlistitems_response.get('tokenPagination', {}).get('nextPageToken')` when it 
should read `playlistitems_response.get('nextPageToken')`.

Comment: Yup. I've finally found it after hours or debugging, should've just used the Explorer API to verify that `tokenPagination` isn't used anymore. Thanks for all your help Trii.
Googlers working on YouTube - This snippet is in a LOT of code all over, please update it.